# Indy FTP, large files and NAT routers

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy

I have been using Indy to transfers files via FTP for years now but have not been able to find a satisfactory solution for the following problem.

When a user is uploading a large file, behind a router, sometimes the following happens: the file is uploaded OK, but in the mean time the command channel gets disconnected because of a timeout. Normally this doesn't happens with a direct connection to the server, because the server "knows" that a transfer is being taking place on the data channel. Some routers are not aware of this, though and the command channel is closed.

Many programs send a NOOP command periodically to keep the command channel alive even if this is not part of the standard FTP specification. My question: how do I do that? Do I send the NOOP command in the OnWork event? Does this cause any collateral damage in some way, like, do I need to process some response? How do I best solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use several approaches to handle this:  (1) Enable [TCP/IP keepalives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819735.aspx) on the control channel during transfers, and (2) recover gracefully after the connection drops, (3) support resuming broken transfers.

A lot of FTP clients will send NOOPs while everything is idle, but I don't know if any that send them during a data transfer because you would need to handle the responses in that case, and many servers won't send them back until the data is finished transferring.

1. Indy 10.5.8 (Delphi XE2) supports TCP/IP keep alives natively.  Just use TIdFTP's `NATKeepAlive` property.

   For previous releases,  assign the OnDataChannelCreate/OnDataChannelDestroy events:

   ```
   const
     KeepAliveIdle = 2 * SecsPerMin;
     KeepAliveInterval = 2 * SecsPerMin;
     IOC_VENDOR = $18000000;
     SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS = DWORD(IOC_IN or IOC_VENDOR or 4);

   type
     tcp_keepalive = record
       onoff: u_long;
       keepalivetime: u_long;
       keepaliveinterval: u_long;
     end;

   procedure TFtpConnection.DataChannelCreated(Sender: TObject;
     ADataChannel: TIdTCPConnection);
   var
     Socket: TIdSocketHandle;
     ka: tcp_keepalive;
     Bytes: DWORD;
   begin
     // Enable/disable TCP/IP keepalives.  They're very small (40-byte) packages
     // and will be sent every KeepAliveInterval seconds after the connection has
     // been idle for KeepAliveIdle seconds.  In Win9x/NT4 the idle and timeout
     // values are system wide and have to be set in the registry;  the default is
     // idle = 2 hours, interval = 1 second.
     Socket := (FIdFTP.IOHandler as TIdIOHandlerSocket).Binding;
     if Win32MajorVersion >= 5 then begin
       ka.onoff := 1;
       ka.keepalivetime := KeepAliveIdle * MSecsPerSec;
       ka.keepaliveinterval := KeepAliveInterval * MSecsPerSec;
       WSAIoctl(Socket.Handle, SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS, @ka, SizeOf(ka), nil, 0, @Bytes,
         nil, nil)
     end
     else
       Socket.SetSockOpt(Id_SOL_SOCKET, Id_SO_KEEPALIVE, Id_SO_True)
   end;

   procedure TFtpConnection.DataChannelDestroy(ASender: TObject;
     ADataChannel: TIdTCPConnection);
   var
     Socket: TIdSocketHandle;
   begin
     Socket := (FIdFTP.IOHandler as TIdIOHandlerSocket).Binding;
     Socket.SetSockOpt(Id_SOL_SOCKET, Id_SO_KEEPALIVE, Id_SO_False)
   end;
   ```
2. To recover gracefully if the file has been successfully transferred, just reconnect at the end and do a **SIZE** or **LIST** to get the file size.  If they match then the file was successfully transferred and you don't need to do anything else.  If the server supports it you can also send an **XCRC** command to get the CRC value, so you can compare it to the local file.
3. If you want to be really robust, you can also check `TIdFTP.CanResume`.  If it's set the server supports the **REST** command, so you can pick up transferring where you left off, by passing `true` to the `AResume` parameter of `TIdFTP.Get/Put`.

Comment: Hello Craig! That seems like a great solution. I have some questions, though. The original problem was that the *command* channel was being closed. If I understand your code correctly you are assigning the keepalive to the data channel?

Comment: This code does affect the command channel (FIdFTP is the TIdFTP object, and FIdFTP.IOHandler represents the command channel).  The reason it's in DataChannelCreate/Destroy is because I'm only enabling it while there's a data channel open.  You could do it immediately after `Connect` instead, but if you're not sending commands (like NOOP), the server would still disconnect you as idle, so that would just cause needless network traffic.

Comment: Just another question. In the DataChannelDestroy you just disable the KeepAlive in case of 9x/NT but not for newer OSs. Shouldn't WSAIoctl be used again with ka.onoff=0? of does Socket.SetSockOpt(Id_SOL_SOCKET, Id_SO_KEEPALIVE, Id_SO_False)
works for newer systems as well?

Comment: SetSockOpt works for both; WSAIoctl is just needed to set the timeout and interval values.  Details in the Remarks section, under SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741621%28VS.85%29.aspx